# Android: what does "Libcore_io_Posix-throwErrnoException" mean

Tags: android, download

i am writing an application that downloads files from server. Sometimes i got the error trace below. Cannot figure out from googling it

```
09-02 23:36:41.931: E/Posix(5307): [CDS]Libcore_io_Posix-throwErrnoException, functionName: access; errno: No such file or directory
```

Has anyone met this before?